# Sending query string data with apache rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule api/rest/v1.0/(.*)$ api/rest/v1.0/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

but if I send this: `http://localhost/api/rest/v1.0/users/list?user_id=123abc&api_key=12` as a test, I get the following `QUERY_STRING` $_SERVER parameter:

```
"QUERY_STRING": "request=users\/list&user_id=123abc",
```

I’m pretty new to RewriteRules and although I have a basic understanding of what is going on, I can’t understand why I’d be able to see user_id and not api_key (or any extra parameters after user_id)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure something in your code isn't stripping that out?

Comment: Yeah, I just `print_r`’d the contents of both $_SERVER and $_REQUEST and they only show values for `request` and `user_id`

Comment: OK, so I’m using cURL in Terminal on the Mac and it seems to be treating the URL weirdly. curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost/api/rest/v1.0/users/list?user_id=123&api_key=123

Comment: I just tested it in the browser and it works as I expected, what am I doing wrong in curl?

Comment: RewriteLog / LogLevel rewrite:trace8 would settle it pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use curl/wget/netcat, you need to prevent your shell from seeing the "&". Safest is to double-quote your URL.

Comment: (via the comments, impossible to nail this via just the question)